# Why is this Post operation failing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, controller, repository, asp.net-web-api-routing

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646715/how-can-i-call-a-web-api-post-method), for my Web API project, I'm using this code on the client:

```
private void AddDepartment()
{
    int onAccountOfWally = 42;
    string moniker = "Billy Bob";
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
    try
    {
        string uri = String.Format("http://platypi:28642/api/Departments/{0}/{1}", onAccountOfWally, moniker);
        var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
        if (webResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Failed: {0}", webResponse.StatusCode.ToString()));
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
    }
}
```

I reach the breakpoint I set on this line of code:

```
var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
```

...but when I F10 over it (or *try* to F11 into it), it fails with "*The remote server returned an error (411) Length Required*"

The length of *what* is required, Compilerobot?!?

This is my method in the server's Repository class:

```
public void Post(Department department)
{
    int maxId = departments.Max(d => d.Id);
    department.Id = maxId + 1;
    departments.Add(department);
}
```

The Controller code is:

```
public void Post(Department department)
{
    deptsRepository.Post(department);
}
```

My GET methods are working fine; POST is the next step, but I'm stubbing my toe so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not posting anything yet.

When you do.. you need to supply the length of the content. Somewhat like this:

```
byte[] yourData = new byte[1024]; // example only .. this will be your data

webRequest.ContentLength = yourData.Length; // set Content Length

var requestStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream(); // get stream for request

requestStream.Write(yourData, 0, yourData.Length); // write to request stream
```

Comment: According to the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646715/how-can-i-call-a-web-api-post-method, I need this line of code: 
var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
Do I really need a RequestStream in this case (posting data)?

Comment: Yes. `GetResponse` is for retrieving the _response_ from your request. `GetRequestStream` gets the `Stream` that is used to write data for the request. If you want to send something along with the request.. you need to write to it.